# How to clear the cache data in Electron(atom shell)?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, electron

I want to clear cache data in Electron(atom-shell). I don't 
    find any api like gui.App.clearCache()(node-webkit api to clear cache
    data) in Electron. If you find any api or any other way please let me 
    know. comments are appreciated .

Comment: WebContents.session.cookies.get(details, callback)

Answer (score 102):

The Electron stores it's cache in these folders:

Windows:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\<yourAppName>\Cache`

Linux:
`/home/<user>/.config/<yourAppName>/Cache`

OS X:
`/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/<yourAppName>/Cache`

So deleting these folders can also help you.
Of course this is one time solution ;-)

Comment: on Windows you get cache path by `const process = require('process');` `process.env.APPDATA + "\\"+ app.getName() + "\\Cache";` I am not sure will it work on other platforms.

Answer (score 39):

You can use [session.clearCache](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md#sesclearcachecallback) api.

```
var remote = require('remote'); 
var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
win.webContents.session.clearCache(function(){
//some callback.
});
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to clear any remnants of previous login sessions, you'd better use this:

```
loginWindow.webContents.session.clearStorageData()
```

Comment: Is it safe removing their content?

Answer (score 9):

We are using this in our app...

```
const { app, session } = require('electron');

// ...

session.defaultSession.clearStorageData(null, (error: any) => {
  // in our case we need to restart the application
  // app.relaunch();
  // app.exit();
});
```

Update for Electron 7:

```
await session.defaultSession.clearStorageData();
```

Comment: Worked fine without the `await`

Comment: Of course, I just added it to indicate that this action is async ;)

Answer (score 3):

Tried answer from @thegnuu and `session.defaultSession.clearCache();` on Windows, electron v10.1.5.

**Option 1:**
Deleting cache path, `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<appname>\Cache`, directly:

```
_deleteFolder(dirPath) {
        const fs = require('fs');

        // delete directory recursively
        try {
            fs.rmdirSync(dirPath, {recursive: true});
            this._logger.info(`cache clean: ${dirPath} is deleted!`);
        } catch (e) {
            this._logger.error(`cache clean: could not delete  ${dirPath}!`, e);
        }
    }
```

**Option 2**: which also clears the same `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<appname>\Cache` directory

```
const {session}   = require('electron');
session.defaultSession.clearCache();
```

Problem with option 1:

- This method sometimes caused app to abrupt crash (in this case, catch block did not run).
- Also, after app restart, app could not load http assets. Normally after cache folder cleared, when I start app I can see new cache files are created. However, on option 1, app could not load assets, even after second restart. Deleted Cache directory manually, then app started work normally.
- Although I did get log from `` this._logger.info(`cache clean: ${dirPath} is deleted!`); `` the cache directory was not deleted. 5 files were still inside it.
- Tried to use asynchronic `fs.rmdir`, got the same result.

On option 2 I did not face any problems. I guess it is the best option.

Bonus: `session.defaultSession.clearStorageData();` clears `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<app name>\Local Storage` directory

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```js
var remote = require('remote');
var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();

win.WebContents.session.cookies.get(details, callback) // getting cookies
win.WebContents.session.cookies.remove(details, callback) //deleting cookies
```

For more info:                           http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.29.0/api/browser-window/

Comment: this seems to be about cookies, not cache?

Answer (score 0):

you could try `mainWindow.webContents.clearHistory();`
or deleting contents in the app Cache folders (will be recreated on app run).
You can get the path with `app.getPath('userData') + '/Cache'`

Answer (score 0):

when you are developing, in developer tools go to the tab application and in clear storage and clear site data

Comment: How does this help in an electron application?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+I opens up the dev tools in Electron apps. This answer is one of possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful if you just need to quickly clear the cache without writing code for it for a one time thing.  The original question wasn't clear that it needed a code solution or a 1 time solution.