# electron zoomFactor not having any effect

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor

I'm very confused.  When I run electron using 'npm  start' where I have a script that starts my node server and then electron: 'node server/app && electron .'

Everything works fine except the the resolution is incredibly zoomed in. On top of that, setting the zoom factor in my main.js file has essentially no effect.

However, when I manually call 'electron .'  Everything works as normal.   The resolution is fine and electron responds to setting the zoomFactor property.

Here is my main.js file:

```
var electron = require('electron'),
app = electron.app,
BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow,
Menu = electron.Menu,
ipcMain = electron.ipcMain;


var socketUtil = require('./server/socket/socket-util');
var url = require('url');
var win;
var forceQuit = false;
var menuTemplate = [{
    label: 'Sample',
    submenu: [
        {label: 'About App', click: function(item, focusedWindow){
            focusedWindow.webContents.send('changeState', 'settings.about');
        }},
        {label: 'Quit', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Q', click: function() {forceQuit=true; app.quit();}},
        {label: 'Reload', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+R', click: function() {win.reload();}},
        {
            label: 'Toggle Developer Tools',
            accelerator: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Alt+Command+I' : 'Ctrl+Shift+I',
            click: function (item, focusedWindow) {
                if (focusedWindow) focusedWindow.webContents.toggleDevTools()
            }
        },
        {label: 'Import Project', click: importProject},
        {
            label: 'Prefs',
            click: function(item, focusedWindow){
                focusedWindow.webContents.send('changeState', 'settings.project');
            }
        }
    ]
}];

var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);

function importProject() {
    win.webContents.send('import:project');
}

function createWindow () {

    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 750,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
            zoomFactor: 1
        }
    });

    var express = require('./server/app')();

    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: 'http://localhost:9000'
    }));

    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    win.on('closed', function(e) {
        win = null;
    })
}

app.on('before-quit', function (e) {
    console.log('');
    console.log('before-quit');
    if(!forceQuit){
        console.log('no force quit');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log('yes force quit');
        beforeQuitThenQuit();
    }
});

app.on('activate-with-no-open-windows', function(){
    console.log('');
    console.log('activate-with-no-open-windows');
    win.show();
});

app.on('ready', function() {
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
    createWindow();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        console.log('quitting app now.');
        forceQuit = true;
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', function() {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
});


function beforeQuitThenQuit() {
    socketUtil.resetClientData().then(function() {
        console.log('resetClientData promise resolved');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the difference I was experiencing was due to the fact that I had electron version 1.3.5 installed globally while locally I was using the latest stable version (and other releases as I tried them).  So npm was utilizing the local electron package while when I used the 'electron .' command directly, I was utilizing the global package.

However I'm still uncertain why the later versions of electron are not taking the zoomFactor into account.

Comment: I added a zoomfactor and it worked, then undid it and now the zoomFactor is stuck somehow. Even if I change it to a whole different factor, it remains to what I initially changed it to. Maybe it's some kind of Electron cache..

Comment: It turned out to be the cache indeed; clearing this resolved the issue for me. To find the cache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44675132/251961