# electronjs BrowserView - How long cache persists?

Tags: electron

I have a web app and a desktop app of the web app built using electronjs BrowserView. In electronjs app, it calls the following code to load the web app.

The problem I recently encountered was that it kept on using old assets, no matter the web app starts using the new assets. I made it point to new assets locally by deleting the files mentioned under this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44675132.

I am assuming that electronjs cache the assets similar to browser cache assets. I am just curious what is the TTL of the cached assets? How long will it take to fetch new assets automatically? Or should I have to do anything so that it starts fetching new assets after every X seconds/minutes time? like sending the `Cache-Control` header?

```
webContents.loadURL("https://mywebapp.com")
```

Note: I am new to electronjs, so pardon me if you find this question silly.